# How can set the Reset button to reset everything also when the timer and stopwatch are not running?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace StopwatchTimer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        private long diff = 0, previousTicks = 0, ticksDisplayed = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            richTextBox1.TabStop = false;
            richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            richTextBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            richTextBox1.Enter += RichTextBox1_Enter; ;

            UpdateTime();
        }

        private void RichTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Focus();
        }

        private void UpdateTime()
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = GetTimeString(watch.Elapsed);
        }

        private string GetTimeString(TimeSpan elapsed)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            //calculate difference in ticks
            diff = elapsed.Ticks - previousTicks;

            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            { //counting up
                ticksDisplayed += diff;
            }
            else
            { //counting down
                ticksDisplayed -= diff;
            }

            if (ticksDisplayed < 0)
            {
                ticksDisplayed = 0;
            }

            //Make ticksDisplayed to regular time to display in richtextbox
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ticksDisplayed);

            result = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
                ctimeSpan.Hours,
                ctimeSpan.Minutes,
                ctimeSpan.Seconds,
                ctimeSpan.Milliseconds);

            previousTicks = elapsed.Ticks;

            return result;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnStart.Text == "START")
            {
                watch.Reset();
                watch.Start();
                UpdateTime();
                btnStart.Text = "STOP";
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                watch.Stop();
                btnStart.Text = "START";
                btnPause.Text = "PAUSE";
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            watch.Reset();
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, trackBarHours.Value, trackBarMinutes.Value, trackBarSeconds.Value, 0);
            diff = 0;
            previousTicks = 0;
            ticksDisplayed = ctimeSpan.Ticks;
            trackBarHours.Value = 0;
            trackBarMinutes.Value = 0;
            trackBarSeconds.Value = 0;
            richTextBox1.Text = "00:00:00.000";
        }

        private void trackBarHours_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get ticksDisplayed as TimeSpan
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ticksDisplayed);
            //change only the hour
            TimeSpan htimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ctimeSpan.Days, trackBarHours.Value, ctimeSpan.Minutes, ctimeSpan.Seconds, ctimeSpan.Milliseconds);

            //set it to ticksDisplayed and update.
            ticksDisplayed = htimeSpan.Ticks;


            UpdateTime();
        }

        private void trackBarMinutes_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ticksDisplayed);
            TimeSpan mtimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ctimeSpan.Days, ctimeSpan.Hours, trackBarMinutes.Value, ctimeSpan.Seconds, ctimeSpan.Milliseconds);

            ticksDisplayed = mtimeSpan.Ticks;


            UpdateTime();
        }

        private void trackBarSeconds_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ticksDisplayed);
            TimeSpan stimeSpan = new TimeSpan(ctimeSpan.Days, ctimeSpan.Hours, ctimeSpan.Minutes, trackBarSeconds.Value, ctimeSpan.Milliseconds);

            ticksDisplayed = stimeSpan.Ticks;


            UpdateTime();
        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnStart.Text == "STOP")
            {
                if (btnPause.Text == "PAUSE")
                {
                    btnPause.Text = "CONTINUE";
                    watch.Stop();
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnPause.Text = "PAUSE";
                    watch.Start();
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTime();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the button reset click event:

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            watch.Reset();
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, trackBarHours.Value, trackBarMinutes.Value, trackBarSeconds.Value, 0);
            diff = 0;
            previousTicks = 0;
            ticksDisplayed = ctimeSpan.Ticks;
            trackBarHours.Value = 0;
            trackBarMinutes.Value = 0;
            trackBarSeconds.Value = 0;
            richTextBox1.Text = "00:00:00.000";
        }
```

While the timer is running after clicking the start button and then clicking the reset button it's working fine and will reset the timer and the timer will start counting over from 00:00:00.000

But when changing the trackbar/s value/s before clicking the start button and then clicking the reset button it's not reseting it to 00:00:00.000 after that if I will click on start it will start from the last changes I did with the trackbars even if I clicked first the reset button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in `btnReset_Click` event . You are doing the following:

```
            TimeSpan ctimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, trackBarHours.Value, trackBarMinutes.Value, trackBarSeconds.Value, 0);
            ticksDisplayed = ctimeSpan.Ticks;
```

So `ctimeSpan` will take the current `trackBarHours.Value`, `trackBarMinutes.Value` and `trackBarSeconds.Value` and set it as `ticksDisplayed` and will be used for next calculation. If you want to reset the time completely to "00:00:00.000" then you have to rewrite the above code as:

```
            ticksDisplayed = 0;
```